# Openfire Roster communication only

Tags: ubuntu, openfire, strophe.js, rosters

I am trying to implement a webchat using **Openfire** as a server. (at this moment i am using *version 4.0.2*) and implementing a web client using **Strophe.js**

I would like to know if there is a way to restrict the communication between users that are in their roster.

Example:

- User Alice have in roster [Charlie]
- User Bob have in roster [Charlie]
- User Charlie have in roster [Alice, Bob]

So the users **can only** communicate with each ohter are:
Alice + Charlie
Bob + Charlie

**But**

Alice and Bob cannot talk with each other.

Other important thing would be the roster can only be managed by the administrator

**NOTES**

I Have already made some experiences and at this moment with Openfire everybody can talk with everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems like you need custom functionality, because Openfire works on XMPP standards and in XMPP i can communicate with anyone having a Jabber ID, just like I can communicate with anyone on WhatsApp if I have their contact number (Jabber ID).

One possible hack can be to add custom code in Openfire, when message is being routed, you can check if the recipient exists in the roster of sender. And make the decision on that.

However, Roster management by an administrator can be done without any changes. User rosters can be managed from Openfire Admin Interface.